# leiningen-win-installer fails to run REPL

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I've just installed [Leiningen Win v 1.0.0](https://bitbucket.org/djpowell/leiningen-win-installer/downloads/leiningen-installer-1.0.exe) and tried to open REPL with JKD 7 (and JDK 8), but it fails on the first attempt. There is not bug tracker in the original [project](http://bitbucket.org/djpowell/leiningen-win-installer) and I wonder if community can help.

*Log:*

`Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

```
PS C:\Users\User> lein repl
nREPL server started on port 53308 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:53308
REPL-y 0.3.2, nREPL 0.2.0-beta5Exception in thread "nREPL-worker-0" NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.l
ength()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nr
epl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)java.lang.NoSuch
MethodError: clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session$session_out$fn__7630.doInvoke(session.clj:43)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session.proxy$java.io.Writer$ff19274a.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
        at clojure.core$fn__5471.invoke(core_print.clj:191)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
        at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
        at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:3437)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:3457)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.main$repl_caught.invoke(main.clj:158)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569$fn__7582.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:76
)
        at clojure.main$repl$fn__6634.invoke(main.clj:259)
        at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:257)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:56)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:41)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__7610$fn__7613.invoke(interruptible_e
val.clj:171)
        at clojure.core$comp$fn__4192.invoke(core.clj:2402)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__7603.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:138)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
#<Namespace user>

Error loading namespace; falling back to userException in thread "nREPL-worker-1" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.t
ools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()INoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure.tools.nrepl.middl
eware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I  clojure
.tools.nrepl.middleware.session/session-out/fn--7630 (session.clj:43)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session$session_out$fn__7630.doInvoke(session.clj:43)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:460)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.session.proxy$java.io.Writer$ff19274a.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456)
        at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473)
        at clojure.core$fn__5471.invoke(core_print.clj:191)
        at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:231)
        at clojure.core$pr_on.invoke(core.clj:3392)
        at clojure.core$pr.invoke(core.clj:3404)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:154)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:132)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$prn.doInvoke(core.clj:3437)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$println.doInvoke(core.clj:3457)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
        at clojure.main$repl_caught.invoke(main.clj:158)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569$fn__7582.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:76
)
        at clojure.main$repl$fn__6634.invoke(main.clj:259)
        at clojure.main$repl.doInvoke(main.clj:257)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:1096)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate$fn__7569.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:56)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:152)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:144)
        at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:624)
        at clojure.core$with_bindings_STAR_.doInvoke(core.clj:1862)
        at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$evaluate.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:41)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$interruptible_eval$fn__7610$fn__7613.invoke(interruptible_e
val.clj:171)
        at clojure.core$comp$fn__4192.invoke(core.clj:2402)
        at clojure.tools.nrepl.middleware.interruptible_eval$run_next$fn__7603.invoke(interruptible_eval.clj:138)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
user=>`
```

Answer (score 1):

This is Leiningen issue, it's fixed in master (https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/1625)

Comment: But can I run the `lein repl` regardless?

Comment: Ouch no. Trivial things work, but then: `(fn [x y] function(println "Making a set")  #{x y})`: `NoSuchMethodError clojure.tools.nrepl.StdOutBuffer.length()I`